# Building Dynamic Variable Names in KornShell

Tags: shell, variables, dynamic, ksh

I did a search but did not find anything quite like what I am trying to do. 
I have a list of Server Hostnames & IPs

- Servera | IPa
- Serverb | IPb
- Servern | IPn

I want to cat this file and put each element into variables

- Server_Var_1
- IP_Var_1
- Server_Var_2
- IP_Var_2
- Server_Var_n
- IP_Var_n

What I currently have is the following KornShell (ksh):

```
Counter=0
cat hostfile|while read line; do
Server_Var_"$Counter"=echo $line | awk -F"|" '{print $1}'
IP_Var_"$Counter"=echo $line | awk -F"|" '{print $2}'
echo $Server_Var_[*] $IP_Var_[*]
done
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat hostfile
server1 | 192.168.1.101
server2 | 192.168.1.102
server3 | 192.168.1.103
$ cat foo
#!/bin/sh

counter=0
while IFS=" |" read name ip; do
    eval Server_VAR_$counter=$name
    eval IP_VAR_$counter=$ip
    : $(( counter += 1 ))
done < hostfile

echo $Server_VAR_0:$IP_VAR_0
echo $Server_VAR_1:$IP_VAR_1
echo $Server_VAR_2:$IP_VAR_2
$ ./foo
server1:192.168.1.101
server2:192.168.1.102
server3:192.168.1.103
```

Comment: Being picky, the OP asks for variables to start from 1, not zero `counter=1`.  Incrementing the counter can be written simply as `(( counter += 1 ))`.

Comment: @cdarke `(( counter += 1 ))` is a bashism (which is an odd word for a construct that may or may not work in ksh (as in I don't know)), but `: $(( counter += 1 ))` is posix.

Comment: Your POSIX point is accepted.  `(( counter += 1 ))` was even in ksh88, so it pre-dates bash, and this question was flagged as referring to ksh.

Comment: The (( ... )) construct originates from ksh indeed.  Pity it isn't in POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slight twist to the original question (which was perfectly answered by @William Pursell).  So this bit of code will produce the same output, but uses an array of compound variables instead.  Note that this is specific to `ksh93`.

```sh
$ cat  read_hostvars

#!/bin/sh

counter=0
typeset -a Server
while IFS=" |" read name ip; do
    Server[counter].name=$name
    Server[counter].ip=$ip
    (( counter++ ))
done < hostfile

for n in ${!Server[@]}; do
    echo ${Server[n].name}:${Server[n].ip}
done
```