# AIX (KSH) Dynamic Variable Assignment - Split long string into multiple lines and assign each line to variables

Tags: shell, ksh, aix

On AIX (Korn Shell), how could I achieve dynamic variable name generation and assignment?

I basically have a string as "LINE 1 LINE 2 LINE 3 LINE 4 LINE 5" and I want this long string to be split into multiple lines (each 7 Characters Long) and assign those to dynamically generated variables such as msg_txt_line_1, msg_txt_line_2 and so on.

I looked for information on Internet and using some help from [Building Dynamic Variable Names in KornShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292122/building-dynamic-variable-names-in-ksh) i built this snippet so far but it gives errors.

**foo.sh**

```
TEXT='LINE 1 LINE 2 LINE 3 LINE 4 LINE 5'
counter=1
echo $TEXT | fmt -7 | while read line ; do eval msg_txt_line_$counter=$line;counter=$(( counter += 1 )) ; done
echo $msg_txt_line_1
echo $msg_txt_line_2
echo $msg_txt_line_3
echo $msg_txt_line_4
echo $msg_txt_line_5
```

The error is

```
AIX:>foo.sh
foo.sh[4]: 1:  not found.
foo.sh[4]: 2:  not found.
foo.sh[4]: 3:  not found.
foo.sh[4]: 4:  not found.
foo.sh[4]: 5:  not found.
```

Thanks for your guidance.

---

I have been working on this and with the comments from JS, I have managed to write the following script which works fine. This can still be improved though for example if the long line contains characters such as `, ", ', and Shell special characters? Appreciate if someone could help me improve this snippet.

```
x=1
TEXT="No one is going to hand me success. I must go out & get it myself. That's why I'm here. To dominate. To conquer. Both the world, and myself."
echo "$TEXT" | fmt -30 | while IFS=$'\n' read -r line; do export msg_txt_line_$x="$line"; let "x=x+1";done
echo "$msg_txt_line_1"
echo "$msg_txt_line_2"
echo "$msg_txt_line_3"
echo "$msg_txt_line_4"
echo "$msg_txt_line_5"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can create an array and then assign values. Something like:</strike>

```
$ TEXT='LINE 1 LINE 2 LINE 3 LINE 4 LINE 5'
$ echo "$TEXT" | fmt -w7 > myfile
$ while IFS=$'\n' read -r line; do export msg_txt_line_$((++x))="$line"; done <myfile
$ echo "$msg_txt_line_1"
LINE 1
```

#### Update:

```
$ TEXT='LINE 1 LINE 2 LINE 3 LINE 4 LINE 5'
$ echo "$TEXT" | fmt -w7 > myfile
$ while IFS=$'\n' read -r line; do export msg_txt_line_$((++x))="$line"; done <myfile
$ echo "$msg_txt_line_1"
LINE 1
```

Comment: Thanks JS but it fails with this error . . . What shell did you execute your commands on?

> [/home/u0012734] > TEXT='LINE 1 LINE 2 LINE 3 LINE 4 LINE 5'
> [/home/u0012734] > IFS=$'\n'
> [/home/u0012734] > array=($(fmt -7 <<< "$TEXT"))
> ksh: 0403-057 Syntax error: `(' is not expected.

Comment: I ran the commands in `ksh`, though it was done on a mac since I don't have AIX box to test with.

Comment: Try doing `arry=( \`fmt -7 <<< "TEXT"\` )` instead of `array=($(fmt -7 <<< "$TEXT"))`. Make sure `IFS=$'\n'` is on the same line and not a separate one.

Comment: I still get the same error... [/home/u0012734] > IFS=$'\n' arry=( `fmt -7 <<< "TEXT"` )
ksh: 0403-057 Syntax error: `(' is not expected.

Comment: What version are you using? Can you do `ksh --version`?

Comment: @Guddu Try the new solution.

Comment: Thanks JS but it still does not work. http://dpaste.com/1269801/ has the session transcript.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32304/discussion-between-guddu-and-js)

Comment: Hi JS . . . A Slight variation of your answer worked fine for me. I have update the original post with my snippet. I am sure it can still be improved. For example. will this code work with special characters such as ` or " or ' in the message text?

Comment: AIX has two ksh versions.  Now I can't recall their names.  Do: ls /usr/bin/ksh* and you will see.  I think the one with the number more closely matches what the Mac has.